# Problem with SystemOutRule and DEBUG stack

Tags: java, spring

Hey i have problem with SystemOutRule log and test in JUnit (4.12).

I have simple Test class:

> ```
> package com.example.demo;
>
> import config.FootballerConfig;
>
> import org.junit.Assert;
> import org.junit.Rule;
> import org.junit.Test;
> import org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.SystemOutRule;
> import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
> import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
> import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
>
>
> import static org.junit.Assert.*;
>
> @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
> @ContextConfiguration(classes = FootballerConfig.class)
> public class FootballerConfigTest {
>
>     @Rule
>     public final SystemOutRule log = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();
>
>     @Autowired
>     private FootballerStats footballerStats;
>
>     @Autowired
>     private Footballer footballer;
>
>     @Test
>     public void footballerShouldNotBeNull() {
>         assertNotNull(footballer);
>     }
>
>     @Test
>     public void getPosition() {
>         footballerStats.getPosition();
>         Assert.assertEquals("I'm playing as defender", log.getLogWithNormalizedLineSeparator().trim());
>     }
> }
> ```

The output I expect is: "I'm playing as defender" but SystemOutRule gives all a whole track stack like:

18:37:32.501 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener

- Before test method: context [DefaultTestContext@7ce3cb8e testClass = FootballerConfigTest, testInstance = com.example.demo.FootballerConfigTest@1139b2f3, testMethod = getPosition@FootballerConfigTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@78b66d36 testClass = FootballerConfigTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class config.FootballerConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@51931956, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51b7e5df, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@45f45fa1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@16aa0a0a], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null], method annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null]. 18:37:32.514 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate
- Retrieved ApplicationContext [1233990028] from cache with key [[MergedContextConfiguration@78b66d36 testClass = FootballerConfigTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class config.FootballerConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@51931956, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51b7e5df, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@45f45fa1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@16aa0a0a], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]] 18:37:32.514 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@455b6df1 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 2, missCount = 1] 18:37:32.516 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate
- Retrieved ApplicationContext [1233990028] from cache with key [[MergedContextConfiguration@78b66d36 testClass = FootballerConfigTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class config.FootballerConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@51931956, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51b7e5df, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@45f45fa1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@16aa0a0a], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]] 18:37:32.516 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@455b6df1 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 3, missCount = 1] 18:37:33.290 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate
- Retrieved ApplicationContext [1233990028] from cache with key [[MergedContextConfiguration@78b66d36 testClass = FootballerConfigTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class config.FootballerConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@51931956, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@51b7e5df, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@45f45fa1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@16aa0a0a], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]] 18:37:33.290 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@455b6df1 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 4, missCount = 1] I'm playing as defender

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I did it. It was enough to use log.clear () in the getPosition() method.

```
@Test
public void getPosition() {
    log.clearLog();
    footballerStats.getPosition();
    Assert.assertEquals("I'm playing as defender\n", log.getLogWithNormalizedLineSeparator());
}
```